# How can I only download the .parquet files of a HuggingFace dataset without generating the .arrow files once the download is completed?

Tags: python, download, parquet, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I want to download all the .parquet files of HuggingFace dataset, e.g. [`uonlp/CulturaX`](https://huggingface.co/datasets/uonlp/CulturaX), without generating the .arrow files once the download is completed.

If I use:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
ds = load_dataset("uonlp/CulturaX", "ar")
```

It will download all the .parquet files of HuggingFace dataset but it will also generate the .arrow files once the download is completed:

[image]

- `downloads` contains the .parquet files.
- `uonlp___cultura_x` contains the .arrow files.

How can I only download the .parquet files of a HuggingFace dataset without generating the .arrow files once the download is completed?

Answer (score 0):

my workaroud:

```py
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download

snapshot_download(
    repo_id="uonlp/CulturaX",
    repo_type="dataset",
    local_dir="data",
    local_dir_use_symlinks=False,
    allow_patterns=["ar/*.parquet"],
    token="..."
)
```